# Django ForeignKey form field: display value

Tags: django, django-forms

I might just be having a brain fart, but I seriously can't figure this out. How do I get display the values of `ForeignKey` fields from a bound form in a template? `{{ field }}` renders a widget, `{{ field.value }}` returns the `pk`, and I need the model itself.

I am writing a custom template for django-crispy-forms; which is why I only get a form field in my context, but not a model field.

Comment: You should show how you are creating and displaying your form. Usually you just use `{{ form.field }}` and it outputs the whole select field for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman There, edited.

Answer (score 7):

You must try this: {{ form.instance.field }}

Comment: wish i found this 3 hrs back :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Shows nothing. I am trying to edit a form with some fields not being editable.